# Is it possible to display an image with text next to the pointer while dragging an object?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a `TreeTableView` and I want to drag its items showing an image and a text that I define in a `Label` next to the mouse pointer. The problem is that the `dragDetected` method belongs to a different class from where the `Label` was defined and I can not access it.

The two classes are these (I have obviated the superfluous parts):

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // here I define and fill the TreeTableView
    ...
    treeTableView.setRowFactory (new Factory());
    ...
    }
}

public class Factory implements Callback
   <TreeTableView <ClassDataType>, TreeTableRow <ClassDataType >> {    
   private void dragDetected (MouseEvent event, TreeTableRow <ClassDataType> row, TreeTableView <ClassDataType> tableTree) {                                 
      label.setText ("text"); // ERROR: label is not accessible
      label.setGraphic (new ImageView (new Image ("image.png")));
      WritableImage image = label.snapshot (new SnapshotParameters (), null);
      db.setDragView (label.snapshot (new SnapshotParameters (), null));
   }
}
```

Comment: What does prevent you to put a `Text` or a `Label` over an `Image` in a `Node` (`StackPane` for example) and to snapshot it like you did with a `Text` only ?

Comment: I'm in the dragDetected method inside the Factory class and I do not know how to access the other controls of the scene defined in the main class to be able to do that.

Comment: If you want a complete answer, please add a MCVE to define what is your blocking point.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Label` object then use the `setText` method to add the text and the `setGraphics` method for the image. the rest should be the same as a Text or Image.